# How do i continue working with Amplify on a new machine?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

I'm using react native for my project. On my old machine, when i ran amplify status, i had `Auth`, `Api` and `Storage` services listed.

I moved to my new machine, installed node, watchman, brew etc... and then navigated to my react native project and ran: `react-native run-ios`, and voila, my app is running. All the calls to my AWS Api, Auth and Storage are working perfectly.

Now i can make some amplify commands. Such as `amplify status`. I tried: `amplify env add`: here's what i got:

```
Users-MBP-2:projectname username$ amplify env add
Note: It is recommended to run this command from the root of your app directory
? Do you want to use an existing environment? Yes
? Choose the environment you would like to use: dev
Using default provider  awscloudformation
✖ There was an error initializing your environment.
init failed
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/username/.aws/credentials'
    at Object.openSync (fs.js:462:3)
    at Proxy.readFileSync (fs.js:364:35)
    at Object.readFileSync (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/util.js:95:26)
    at IniLoader.parseFile (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/shared-ini/ini-loader.js:6:47)
    at IniLoader.loadFrom (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/shared-ini/ini-loader.js:56:30)
    at Config.region (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/node_loader.js:100:36)
    at Config.set (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/config.js:507:39)
    at Config.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/config.js:342:12)
    at Config.each (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/util.js:507:32)
    at new Config (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/config.js:341:19) {
  errno: -2,
  syscall: 'open',
  code: 'ENOENT',
  path: '/Users/username/.aws/credentials'
}
```

Do you think credentials info needs to be brought/configured to my new machine?

When i run `amplify configure project` it's like doing an `amplify init` and building a project from scratch. I'm being asked:

```
? Enter a name for the project: ProjectName
? Choose your default editor: Visual Studio Code
? Choose the type of app that you're building javascript
Please tell us about your project
? What javascript framework are you using (Use arrow keys)
  angular 
  ember 
  ionic 
  react 
❯ react-native 
  vue 
  none 
etc....
```

I also already have a region, username and accessKey, secretAccess key etc..

I do not want to replace or ruin anything in my current backend or current project! Whats going on?

Answer (score 6):

1. Ensure amplify-cli is installed and you're logged in with your AWS details.

```
    npm install -g @aws-amplify/cli
    amplify configure
```

Running amplify configure is mainly to give the cli knowledge of your AWS account so subsequent commands can have access to things.

If you get `amplify: command not found` errors try restarting your terminal. If still no luck, you will need to check amplify has been added to your PATH variable.

2. Run `amplify env add` , but choose an existing environment. This will let you choose the environment you created on your other machine so you can pull those settings down to your new machine.

```
    amplify env add
    ? Do you want to use an existing environment?  Yes
    Production
```

Follow up with:

```
amplify pull
```

You don't need to run `amplify add auth` again or anything. All of that will pull down automatically after you've done the above.

Comment: Managed to do it. I had to copy over my .aws folder to /Users/username/.aws

Comment: Great. I was recently in same situation and the above is what solved it for me. Sharing here so other folk can have both options.

Comment: this asks me to create a new IAM user

Answer (score 1):

You DO NOT need to do all config again, but some for sure

You have to install amplify cli `npm install -g @aws-amplify/cli`

use `amplify pull`

https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/start#amplify-pull

Follow the rest of steps - 
-- provide the accessKeyId, secretAccessKey
-- region
-- select amplify project

and then rest of app related thing like IDE, directory......

Comment: Do i have to run 'amplify configure' again? What will 'amplify pull' do? Also, i don't want to screw up the Auth. I already have a cognito pool so that has to continue as so

Comment: This will not change any backend infrastructure

Answer (score 1):

I tried every solution then I found this. (in MacBook)

% **`sudo -i`**
Password:

~ root# **`npm install -g @aws-amplify/cli`**

-- Ctrl+D to exist from Root user

% **`amplify pull --appId xxxx --envName yyyy.`**

> **Note:** To get --appId xxxx --envName yyyy
> Log in to the AWS console. Choose AWS Amplify. Click your app. Go to Backend
> environments. Find the backend environment you wish to pull. Click
> Edit backend. See top right then click 'Local setup instructions
> ' ( amplify pull --appId
> YOUR_APP_ID --envName YOUR_ENV_NAME )

Waiting until it request to verify your amplify.
✔ Successfully received Amplify Studio tokens.
? Choose your default editor: **Visual Studio Code**
? Choose the type of app that you're building javascript
Please tell us about your project
? What javascript framework are you using react
? Source Directory Path:  **src**
? Distribution Directory Path: **build**
? Build Command:  **npm run-script build**
? Start Command: **npm run-script start**
✔ Synced UI components.
? Do you plan on modifying this backend? Yes
⠴ Building resource api/xxxx✅ GraphQL schema compiled successfully.

Edit your schema at ....
✔ Successfully pulled backend environment yyyy from the cloud.
✅

Successfully pulled backend environment staging from the cloud.
Run 'amplify pull' to sync future upstream changes.

% **`amplify pull`**

% **`npm install`**

% **`npm start`**

Hope this help every one!!

Happy Coding :)